# Comparing todays date to a stored date in php

Tags: php, date

I am trying to compare two dates (one stored in the db) and today's date using PHP and outputing a "print" statement based on the result of the comparison.  My expiration date is stored as "datetime" in the db.  It is called through a query and assigned to the variable $expire.  The code I have for the comparison is below, but it always returns false, regardless of the date.

```
<? 
  $todays_date = date("m-d-Y"); 
  $today = strtotime($todays_date); 
  $expired = strtotime($expire); 

  if ($today > $expired) {
    print "<a target='_blank' href='/pdfwriter/generate_certificate.php?member=".$memberID."'>Print Membership Certificate</a>";
  } 
  else 
  {
    print "<a href='registration/registration.aspx?registerType=1'>Membership Expired - Renew Today</a>";
  } 
?>
```

Comment: Functions like `strtotime()` have been deprecated in newer versions. Don't use them.

Comment: Please be specific about the question

Comment: @Lion this is GREAT news, but where have you seen that strtotime() is deprecated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easier to do with `DateTime()` since it make comparing the dates easier. No need to convert to timestamps or anything plus it takes daylight savings time into account. I also *think* your comparison operator is backwards.

```
$today = new DateTime();
$expires = new DateTime($expire);
if ($today < $expires)
{
    print "<a target='_blank' href='/pdfwriter/generate_certificate.php?member=".$memberID."'>Print Membership Certificate</a>";
}
else
{
    print "<a href='registration/registration.aspx?registerType=1'>Membership Expired - Renew Today</a>";
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work either.  I am not a programmer, just trying to make an edit for more functionality.

Comment: Show me a valid date for `$expire`

Comment: In the database it looks like this: 2013-08-06 00:00:00

Comment: Works for me: [expired](http://codepad.org/CMNeEbrv). [Not expired](http://codepad.org/ug1ec4d5).

Comment: Not sure what's wrong.  When I use the new DateTime() it breaks the whole page.  Thanks for trying though.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? If it's really old you may not have access to `DateTime()`.

Comment: My version of PHP is 5.3.23

Comment: That code should work for you then. What is the error message you get? I'd like to get this working for you.